# VS2012 Identifer not found when part of static lib

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, linker, static-libraries

Using VS2012 C/C++:

I created and linked a static lib called "libtools" to my project.
Calls to functions in the libtools lib worked as expected.

I created and linked a second static lib called "shunt" to my project.
But when I incorporate a call to a function in shunt, I am getting a c3861 "Identifier not found"

I added both libs to my project in the same way.  I added a ref to each one in the Framework and References, and added the full path in the C/C++ Additional directories.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the lib shunt contains the identifier you are trying to access? We can't really help you if we don't have more details

Comment: Maybe it's a silly comment to make, but if you follow the same naming convention, "shunt" should read "libshunt" or similar.

Comment: And `libshunt` is not made in C++ when you use the library from C?

Comment: Yes I am sure shunt contains the identifier.  To test this, I used a second function from shunt and got the same error.  @JoachimPileborg: not sure what you are asking...shunt lib is being created, and put into the \shunt\shunt\x64\debug dir, just as libtools is in the \libtools\libtools\x64\debug dir

Comment: Is `libshunt` programmed in C++? Is the application programmed in C? If the answer to both those questions are "yes", then did you forget `extern "C"` in your header files for the function declarations?

Comment: Did you forget to `#include <shunt.h>` or whatever the main header file for your second lib is?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg.  I added  extern "C" int shuntfunc(int)  to my main project file, and that solved the problem.  Not sure why I had to do this, because I did not have to do that for libtools.  Everything, libtools, shunt and my main project are written in.  However, now I get LNK1104 shunt.lib not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ uses something called [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) when it creates symbol names. It's needed because the symbol names must contain the complete function signature. 
When you use `extern "C"` the names will not be mangled, and can be used from other programming languages, like C.

You clearly make the shunt library in C++, which means that the `shuntfunc` function isn't actually named that way once it passed the compiler. As the actual application using the library is made in C (guessing based on the tag and information) it can't find the `shuntfunc` symbol, not without telling the C++ compiler to not mangle the symbol name.

That it works for the other library is probably because it's made in C as well.